# JAVA Methods problem - Calculate speed of car trying to reach a certain distance at a certain time

Tags: java, math, methods

I was tasked to create a program that would calculate how fast you must go to reach a certain distance (miles per hour) at a certain time (in hours). You are supposed to consider a 5 minute break for every 100 miles. Also, the program has to be written using 4 methods and a main method. I already did a majority of the program but I don't know how to properly output my results. I am positive that I am doing something wrong with one of the methods but I don't know how to fix it. Heres what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class I95Machine {

    public static void userMessage() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to I95 Speed Machine");

        System.out.println("You will have to supply:\n+ The distance you want to travel, in miles\n+ The time you have available, in hours");

    }

    public static double computeTravelSpeedOne(double inputDist, double inputTime) {
        double stopTime, travelSpeed;
        int timeQuotient;

        timeQuotient = (int) (inputDist / 100);
        stopTime = timeQuotient * 5;

        if ((timeQuotient % 100) > 0) {
            stopTime += 5;
        }

        stopTime /= 60;

        inputTime = inputTime - stopTime;

        travelSpeed = inputDist / inputTime;

        if (inputTime > 0) {
            return travelSpeed;
        } else {
            return 0.0;
        }
    }

    public static double inputDistAndTime() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double distNum = 0, timeNum = 0, distance, time;

        System.out.print("Enter distance to travel : ");
            distNum = keyboard.nextDouble();
                distance = distNum;
        System.out.print("Enter time available     : ");
            timeNum = keyboard.nextDouble();
                time = timeNum;

        return computeTravelSpeedOne(distance, time);
    }

    public static void displayOutput(double travelSpeed) {
        boolean speedLim = computeTravelSpeedOne() > 65;

        System.out.print("You will have to travel at ");
        System.out.println(computeTravelSpeedOne() + " MPH");
        System.out.print("Over the speed limit     : ");
        System.out.print(speedLim);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        userMessage();
        inputDistAndTime();
        displayOutput();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question, but in displayOutput you call computeTravelSpeedOne without any arguments, this might fail...

Comment: Yea I guess what I am asking is how do I add the arguments? Whenever I do it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: So i realized that rather than separating displayOutput method and inputDistAndTime method I can combine them to one method and the program works.